# Javascript countdown using server-side time to complete

Tags: javascript, php, date

I am using this script to countdown and it works.

```
            <script type="text/javascript">

        (function (e) {
        e.fn.countdown = function (t, n) {
        function i() {
        eventDate = Date.parse(r.date) / 1e3;
        currentDate = Math.floor(e.now() / 1e3);
        if (eventDate <= currentDate) {
        n.call(this);
        clearInterval(interval)
        }
        seconds = eventDate - currentDate;
        days = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
        seconds -= days * 60 * 60 * 24;
        hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
        seconds -= hours * 60 * 60;
        minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        seconds -= minutes * 60;
        days == 1 ? thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("day") : thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("day");
        hours == 1 ? thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hours") : thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hours");
        minutes == 1 ? thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("Minutes") : thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("Minutes");
        seconds == 1 ? thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("Seconds") : thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("Seconds");
        if (r["format"] == "on") {
        days = String(days).length >= 2 ? days : "0" + days;
        hours = String(hours).length >= 2 ? hours : "0" + hours;
        minutes = String(minutes).length >= 2 ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
        seconds = String(seconds).length >= 2 ? seconds : "0" + seconds
        }
        if (!isNaN(eventDate)) {
        thisEl.find(".days").text(days);
        thisEl.find(".hours").text(hours);
        thisEl.find(".minutes").text(minutes);
        thisEl.find(".seconds").text(seconds)
        } else {
        alert("Invalid date. Example: 30 Tuesday 2013 15:50:00");
        clearInterval(interval)
        }
        }
        thisEl = e(this);
        var r = {
        date: null,
        format: null
        };
        t && e.extend(r, t);
        i();
        interval = setInterval(i, 1e3)
        }
        })(jQuery);
        $(document).ready(function () {
        function e() {
        var e = new Date;
        e.setDate(e.getDate() + 60);
        dd = e.getDate();
        mm = e.getMonth() + 1;
        y = e.getFullYear();
        futureFormattedDate = mm + "/" + dd + "/" + y;
        return futureFormattedDate
        }
        $("#countdown").countdown({
        date: "<?php echo $newcounter ?> ", // Change this to your desired date to countdown to
        format: "on"
        });
        });

        </script>
```

This script uses my client date, but i want use my server date. How can read the date read from my server?  I tried this code in my script:

```
currentDate = <?php echo time() ?>;
```

but my countdown stops and does not work.

Comment: Javascript runs client side so if you want the server time you will need to do an AJAX call to the server.

Comment: thank you how can call whit ajax?

Comment: What is the current value you are using on `$newcounter` ?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19228755/2827407

Comment: @APAD1, there's no need of AJAX... He just wants to get the server time on the creation of the page...

Comment: I just answered this question in another thread

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139393/how-to-make-this-javascript-functions-to-actually-gather-server-time-and-countdo/27139420#27139420

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Vienna');
    $now = new DateTime();
    $dateJsFormat = $now->format('Y') .',' . ($now->format('m')-1) .','.$now->format('d') .',' . $now->format('H') .','.$now->format('i');
?>

<script>


  var date = new Date(<?= $dateJsFormat ?>);
  alert(date);

</script>
```

The JS-Date Object expects this format as parameters:

```
new Date(Year, Month, day, hour, minute) // JS-Code
```

The Month must be decremented by 1:

```
$now->format('m')-1 // see php-code above
```

In your example, you have to set this:

```
$("#countdown").countdown({
    date: "<?= dateJsFormat ?>", // Change this to your desired date to countdown to
    format: "on"
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have the server time.  You are going about this correctly - no need to use AJAX.  I think your problem involves the format of the date you ae passing to the countdown function.  The countdown appears to want a number (newcounter = number milliseconds to wait?), but you are passing a timestamp (`<?php echo time() ?>`).

See @APAD1 comment above.