# How to make this javascript functions to actually gather server time and countdown until event starts instead of browser/client time?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

As the title says I am not really good on that and I am struggling how to make that when the event timers are launched it will countdown until event starts getting the time from the server and not counting on browser/client time? In the current way all will miss the event since most have different time zones and its incorrect :)

Give me a clue please. Here is the full function:

```
<?php $d = date('D M d Y H:i:s O'); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var currdate = new Date(<?php $d; ?>);
var day = currdate.getDay();
var hrs = currdate.getHours();
var hrs0 = currdate.getHours();
var hrs00 = currdate.getHours();
var mins = currdate.getMinutes();
var secs = currdate.getSeconds();
var CSWday = 7;
var CSWhrs = 19;
var FThrs1 = 6;
var FThrs2 = 14;
var FThrs3 = 22;
var BDWhrs1 = 5;
var BDWhrs2 = 11;
var BDWhrs3 = 17;
var BDWhrs4 = 23;
var FTmins1 = 59;
var FTsecs1 = 60;
var hrsOut = 0;
var hrsOut2 = 0;

var hrs1 = FThrs1 - hrs;
var hrs2 = FThrs2 - hrs;
var hrs3 = FThrs3 - hrs;

var hrs01 = BDWhrs1 - hrs0;
var hrs02 = BDWhrs2 - hrs0;
var hrs03 = BDWhrs3 - hrs0;
var hrs04 = BDWhrs4 - hrs0;

var day = CSWday - day;
var hrs001 = CSWhrs - hrs00;

if (day == 7)
    day = 0;

if ((hrs > 22) || ((hrs >= 0) && (hrs < 7)))
{
    if (hrs > 22)
        hrsOut = 7;
    else
        hrsOut = hrs1;
}
if ((hrs > 6) && (hrs < 15))
    hrsOut = hrs2;
if ((hrs > 14) && (hrs < 23))
    hrsOut = hrs3;

if ((hrs0 > 23) || ((hrs0 >= 0) && (hrs0 < 6)))
{
    if (hrs0 > 23)
        hrsOut2 = 6;
    else
        hrsOut2 = hrs01;
}
if ((hrs0 > 5) && (hrs0 < 12))
    hrsOut2 = hrs02;
if ((hrs0 > 11) && (hrs0 < 18))
    hrsOut2 = hrs03;
if ((hrs0 > 17) && (hrs0 <= 23))
    hrsOut2 = hrs04;

mins = FTmins1 - mins;
secs = FTsecs1 - secs;

var counter=setInterval(FTTimer, 1000);
var counter=setInterval(BDWTimer, 1000);
var counter=setInterval(CSWTimer, 1000);

function FTTimer()
{
    secs=secs-1;

    if (hrsOut < 0)
    {
        clearInterval(counter);
    }
    else if (mins < 0)
    {
        secs = 59;
        mins = 59;
        hrsOut = hrsOut - 1;
        return;
    }
    else if (secs < 0)
    {
        secs = 59;
        mins = mins - 1;
        return;
    }

    if (secs < 10 && mins < 10 && hrsOut < 10)
        document.getElementById("FTTimer").innerHTML="0"+hrsOut+":0"+mins+":0"+secs;
    else if (mins < 10 && hrsOut < 10)
        document.getElementById("FTTimer").innerHTML="0"+hrsOut+":0"+mins+":"+secs;
    else if (secs < 10 && hrsOut < 10)
        document.getElementById("FTTimer").innerHTML="0"+hrsOut+":"+mins+":0"+secs;
    else if (secs < 10 && mins < 10)
        document.getElementById("FTTimer").innerHTML=hrsOut+":0"+mins+":0"+secs;
    else if (hrsOut < 10)
        document.getElementById("FTTimer").innerHTML="0"+hrsOut+":"+mins+":"+secs;
    else if (mins < 10)
        document.getElementById("FTTimer").innerHTML=hrsOut+":0"+mins+":"+secs;     
    else if (secs < 10)
        document.getElementById("FTTimer").innerHTML=hrsOut+":"+mins+":0"+secs;
    else
        document.getElementById("FTTimer").innerHTML=hrsOut+":"+mins+":"+secs;
}

function BDWTimer()
{
    if (hrsOut2 < 0)
    {
        clearInterval(counter);
    }
    else if (mins < 0)
    {
        secs = 59;
        mins = 59;
        hrsOut2 = hrsOut2 - 1;
        return;
    }
    else if (secs < 0)
    {
        secs = 59;
        mins = mins - 1;
        return;
    }

    if (secs < 10 && mins < 10 && hrsOut2 < 10)
        document.getElementById("BDWTimer").innerHTML="0"+hrsOut2+":0"+mins+":0"+secs;
    else if (mins < 10 && hrsOut2 < 10)
        document.getElementById("BDWTimer").innerHTML="0"+hrsOut2+":0"+mins+":"+secs;
    else if (secs < 10 && hrsOut2 < 10)
        document.getElementById("BDWTimer").innerHTML="0"+hrsOut2+":"+mins+":0"+secs;
    else if (secs < 10 && mins < 10)
        document.getElementById("BDWTimer").innerHTML=hrsOut2+":0"+mins+":0"+secs;
    else if (hrsOut2 < 10)
        document.getElementById("BDWTimer").innerHTML="0"+hrsOut2+":"+mins+":"+secs;
    else if (mins < 10)
        document.getElementById("BDWTimer").innerHTML=hrsOut2+":0"+mins+":"+secs;       
    else if (secs < 10)
        document.getElementById("BDWTimer").innerHTML=hrsOut2+":"+mins+":0"+secs;
    else
        document.getElementById("BDWTimer").innerHTML=hrsOut2+":"+mins+":"+secs;
}

function CSWTimer()
{
    if (day < 0)
    {
        day = 6;
        return;
    }
    else if (hrs001 < 0)
    {
        if (hrs001 == -1)
            hrs001 = 23;
        else if (hrs001 == -2)
            hrs001 = 22;
        else if (hrs001 == -3)
            hrs001 = 21;
        else if (hrs001 == -4)
            hrs001 = 20;
        day = day - 1;
        return;
    }
    else if (mins < 0)
    {
        secs = 59;
        mins = 59;
        hrs001 = hrs001 - 1;
        return;
    }
    else if (secs < 0)
    {
        secs = 59;
        mins = mins - 1;
        return;
    }

    if (secs < 10 && mins < 10 && hrs001 < 10)
        document.getElementById("CSWTimer").innerHTML=day+":0"+hrs001+":0"+mins+":0"+secs;
    else if (mins < 10 && hrs001 < 10)
        document.getElementById("CSWTimer").innerHTML=day+":0"+hrs001+":0"+mins+":"+secs;
    else if (secs < 10 && hrs001 < 10)
        document.getElementById("CSWTimer").innerHTML=day+":0"+hrs001+":"+mins+":0"+secs;
    else if (secs < 10 && mins < 10)
        document.getElementById("CSWTimer").innerHTML=day+":"+hrs001+":0"+mins+":0"+secs;
    else if (hrs001 < 10)
        document.getElementById("CSWTimer").innerHTML=day+":0"+hrs001+":"+mins+":"+secs;
    else if (mins < 10)
        document.getElementById("CSWTimer").innerHTML=day+":"+hrs001+":0"+mins+":"+secs;        
    else if (secs < 10)
        document.getElementById("CSWTimer").innerHTML=day+":"+hrs001+":"+mins+":0"+secs;
    else
        document.getElementById("CSWTimer").innerHTML=day+":"+hrs001+":"+mins+":"+secs;
}
</script>
```

Comment: not sure why you need to even know the clients time if its just going to count down between two numbers. you should be able to use both to work out the servers time til the countdown ends and output the number of milliseconds til that happens, then use js to just count down to 0

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$d = date('D M d Y H:i:s O');
echo "
<script>
var currdate = new Date($d);
</script>
";
?>
```

Comment: Can't I somehow include it directly into the script to get the current date/time? I am not sure what's the best...

Comment: Sure, that makes sense too you can have the server-side script initialize the current date and time that your javascript script will use.

Comment: And now comes the issues how to include all that in my current script and php ? Could you possibly give me an example ?

Comment: So, I can directly change `var currdate = new Date();` to the above in your example and what else in my script must be changed ?

Comment: Yeah so change that line to

var currdate = new Date($d):

All the rest use that date object so you don't need to change anything else.

Comment: Thanks but there is one problem. I can't echo it since it includes total of 3 functions in my above script. What's a better way instead of echo or I am missing something since I echo my whole script ...

Comment: You could make an asynchronous call to your server-side script.

Comment: Excuse me but that seems really advanced for me and I can't ask you to do it for me. Thanks a lot but eventually I will try to find a way to do it myself ...

Comment: Wait, I am confused, why can't you use echo?

Comment: I must echo my whole script as you said right? If you look at my script it containts 3 functions CSWTimer() and etc. So, how to echo only var currdate outside of the function ?

Comment: Another way to do it would be to close the PHP tags like

<?php
//PHP Script here
?>

HTML here <?=$echosomevariable?> more html here

<?php

//More PHP here

?>

Comment: Oh, wait. Did you mean to exclude my var currdate from the current `<script>` and make another for it separately?

Comment: (sorry not sure what you mean by your last comment) ^

Comment: Can you please lastly see my main post ? I've updated my post with what you said, howerver, the timer doesn't show up after doing that. Thanks! I upvote your answer and will accept it shortly. Waiting for your answer please! Thanks in advance